# Почему происходит выполнение всех команд сразу?

Tags: c#

Пишу программу которая бы при вводе команды открывала подвязанное к команде приложение.
Есть Dictionary подобного содержания

```
 static void CommandList (string command)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Process> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Process>();
        Commands.Add("music", Process.Start(@"E:\YandexDisk\Work\C#\SpeechRecognition\bin\Debug\player\AIMP.exe", "/PLAY"));
        Commands.Add("video", Process.Start("notepad.exe"));

        foreach (var c in Commands)
        {
            command = c.Key;
        }
    }
```

При поступлении значения в метод с любым текстом будь то "music" или "video" или просто набор "32132141451". Компьютер сразу открывает оба приложения а не то, которое привязано к ключу словаря или вообще не делает ничего так как нет нужного слова-ключа.
В чем ошибка?

Comment: А где у вас сравнение? Или хотябы поиск по словарю...

Comment: `Process.Start` - что делает? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor Ну как я понимаю запускает нужный мне exe. Но дело в том, что если ввести в строку любую ерунду, запускает мне оба приложения. Я явно чего то не понимаю в этой ситуации:)

Comment: Ну так вы посмотрите на свой код: при входе в процедуру у вас безусловно(!) идет вызов двух Process.Start

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов как правильно сделать, что бы получить то что я хочу?

Comment: Как минимум - добавить поиск по словарю. Но я на .NET не пишу, вопрос не ко мне.

Comment: @Petr "как сделать, что бы получить то что я хочу" - изо всех сил постараться внятно сформулировать, чего Вы хотите.

Comment: @Igor есть программа, которая принимает команды.
Если команда есть в списке то выполняется привязанное к ней приложение.
Ввожу в консоли "music" запускается плеер. Ну или любая другая команда которая будет подвязана.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static Dictionary<string, ProcessStartInfo> CreateCommands()
{
  Dictionary<string, ProcessStartInfo> commands = new Dictionary<string, ProcessStartInfo>();
  commands["music"] = new ProcessStartInfo(@"E:\YandexDisk\Work\C#\SpeechRecognition\bin\Debug\player\AIMP.exe", "/PLAY"));
  commands["video"] = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
  return commands;
}

Dictionary<string, ProcessStartInfo> commands = CreateCommands();
string key = Console.ReadLine();
if (commands.ContainsKey(key))
  Process.Start(commands[key]);
```